# Attempting to display server returned data with an API

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am building a small site that will take a city or zip code and return weather (temp for the time being) data from openweathermap.org.  This is a school assignment and I have been asked to use an asynchronous call.

I know that I am retrieving correct data from the API.  What I don't know is how to take that information and display it to a list item called temperature.  I have included a snippet of my script and html below.

```
 function getWeatherbyZip()
 {
     //event.preventDefault();          
     var zipCode = getZip();
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="+zipCode+",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1", false);
     req.send(null);
     console.log(JSON.parse(req.responseText));

     req.addEventListener('load',function()
     {
          var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
          document.getElementById('temp').textContent = response.main.temp;
     });
 }
```

And the corresponding HTML blocks:

```
 Zipcode: <input type="number" id="myZip" min="11111" max="99999" value="00000"/>
 <input type="button" value="Search by Zipcode" onclick="getWeatherbyZip()"/>

 <li><span><p>Temperature:</p></span><span id="temp"></span></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are supposed to use an *asynchronous* call.  If that's the case, then *why* do you pass `false` to [`req.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open())?  If you remove that, it'll become asynchronous and `req.responseText` won't exist until it's done.  Then your callback will read it correctly.

```js
function getZip() {
  return document.getElementById('myZip').value;
}

function getWeatherbyZip() {
  //event.preventDefault();          
  var zipCode = getZip();
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode + ",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1");
  req.send(null);

  req.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    document.getElementById('temp').textContent = response.main.temp;
  });
}
```

```html
Zipcode: <input type="number" id="myZip" min="11111" max="99999" value="00000" />
<input type="button" value="Search by Zipcode" onclick="getWeatherbyZip()" />

<span><p>Temperature:</p></span><span id="temp"></span>
```

Comment: I must have copied old code because I did have that set to true; my mistakes and thanks for catching that.  

I notice you didn't pass true either, you just nixed false.  Is the default true?  Is that why we do not need to send true?

Comment: Yep, `true` is the default.  :-)  The `async` parameter is optional and defaults to `true`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()